# IIS site not using identity specified in app pool IIS 7 +

Tags: iis, identity, pool

I have a web app from visual studio that is using local IIS server to run. It is an MVC 3 application.  I setup the application pool in my IIS (win 7 pro) to use a service account for the application identity.  When I browse the site I am getting permission errors for a function on the site which I would not get if it was using the service account.  This has been tested by using same service account on a development server as the application pool identity.  Application executes with no errors.  Could there be something in my local security policy preventing the service account from being used?
Service account is also a member of IIS_IUSRS group.
This is a network service.

Comment: Is your app using impersonation? ie trying to use the users' credentials? If so, these may be valid in dev, but not on the other server.

Comment: no its not using impersonation as the user's will never have permissions to do the function required.